# GraphDiff: "Cascading" Owned Collections

Tags: expression-trees, graphdiff

I'm trying to use [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) (latest available version in NuGet) to handle what I consider a not terribly difficult entity model. Consider a model like so:

```
class A 
{
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}
```

If I'm updating an instance of A (call it **aEntity**), I could do:

```
context.UpdateGraph(aEntity, map => 
    map.OwnedCollection(a => a.Bs, withB => 
        withB.OwnedCollection(b => b.Cs)))
```

Now I'd also, sometimes, like to update B's independently.

```
context.UpdateGraph(bEntity, map => map.OwnedCollection(b => b.Cs));
```

So I figured I could "cascade" the changes by introducing a property, like so:

```
class BMapper {
    Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<B>, object>> MappingExpression 
    {
        get 
        {
            return map => map.OwnedCollection(b => b.Cs);
        }
    }
}
```

... and then use that in both scenarios like so:

```
// Update an A and any of its B's
context.UpdateGraph(aEntity, map =>
    map.OwnedCollection(a => a.Bs, (new BMapper()).MappingExpression))

// Update a B by itself
context.UpdateGraph(bEntity, (new BMapper()).MappingExpression);
```

Updating the B by itself works fine, but updating an A falls down in expression land:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 
    'string' does not contain a definition for 'Body'
```

Is there a way to share mappings in GraphDiff?

Comment: Is the questions just: " I want to be able to map cascading properties or the individual property"?

Because you can do that natively with GraphDiff:

context.UpdateGraph(aEntity, map =>
map.OwnedCollection(a => a.Bs, with => 
with
.AssociatedCollection(b => b.Cs)));


Then you can do :

context.UpdateGraph(bEntity);

Right?

Comment: No, the question is whether portions of the cascading property can be defined in their own methods or properties so they can be reused. That way I could define the mapping for a child object (and its own child relations) in one place, and then have parents reuse that code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?